# Игнорирование условия

Tags: python, if

Хочу написать программу решения числовых выражений. Начал делать, и пошла какая-то абракадабра, интерпретатор не смотрит на условие "иначе" и тупо пишет только надпись из верхнего условия. Что с этим делать? + It is number. Вбиваю, например, +, который декларирован как оператор, а он пишет цифра.

````
numbers = exspression.split (maxsplit = len(exspression))
listNumbers = list(numbers)
print ("Verifycation")
print (listNumbers)
lifeNumber = listNumbers
if lifeNumber != None:
   if lifeNumber != '+' or '-' or '(' or ')' or '*'  or '/' or ' ':
      print("It is number")
   else:
      print ("it is operator")```
````

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте еще немного о правилах написания условий.

Надо или так

```
if lifeNumber not in ('+','-','(',')','*','/',' '):
```

или уж если угодно так:

```
if lifeNumber != '+' and lifeNumber != '-' and lifeNumber != '(' .....:
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if lifeNumber != '+' or '-' or '(' or ')' or '*'  or '/' or ' ':
```

это условие у вас будет выполняться ВСЕГДА

во-первых '-' будет восприниматься как `True`, а значит условие всегда будет `True` и будет выполняться ВСЕГДА

во-вторых даже если бы вы написали

```
if lifeNumber != '+' or lifeNumber != '-' or ...:
```

такое условие тоже выполнялось бы ВСЕГДА

покажу на простом примере:

```
if i != 1 or i != 2:
```

1. если `i` не равно 1 или 2 - это условие правдиво
2. если `i` равно 1 и значит оно не равно 2 - это условие опять правдиво
3. если `i` равно 2 и значит оно не равно 1 - это условие опять правдиво

т.е. условие выполняется ВСЕГДА

для вашей задачи  необходимо было бы использовать вместо `or` `and` или же оставить `or` но тогда вместо `!=` надо было бы использовать `==`

но наиболее оптимально использовать оператор `in`

```
if lifeNumber in ('+','-','(',')','*','/',' '):':
    print ("it is operator")
else:
    print("It is number")
```

ну или

```
if lifeNumber not in ('+','-','(',')','*','/',' '):':
    print("It is number")
else:
    print ("it is operator")
```

да и для чисел нужны дополнительные проверки - ведь `1e10` - это тоже число :)

в данном случае можно использовать конструкции `try except`